How to create a transparent color overlay with texture blending effect using CSS and JavaScript?
I’m working on a project where I need to dynamically apply a transparent color overlay to an image that contains a subtle texture. The goal is to blend the selected color with the texture of the image, similar to how paint colors are displayed on a textured surface.
The functionality involves:
Displaying an image (e.g., a textured wall or paint sample).
Allowing users to select a color from a palette.
Dynamically applying the selected color as a semi-transparent overlay on top of the image while preserving the visible texture beneath the color.
The best result I got:

What I would like to achieve:

I have tried using the following:
CSS pseudo-elements with ::after for the overlay.
background-blend-mode: multiply; to combine the overlay color with the texture.
JavaScript to dynamically set the overlay color using inline styles and a rgba() value.
I also use JavaScript to update the overlay color dynamically:
The Problem:
While this approach is working, the texture visibility is not as prominent as i want it to be. You can faintly see the texture through the color overlay (see the attached screenshot), but it's not as clear or vivid as what Novacolor achieves on their site.
What might I be missing?
Are there better techniques in CSS or JavaScript for achieving a more pronounced texture visibility while maintaining a semi-transparent color overlay?
What I've Tried:
Adjusting background-blend-mode values:
Based on the image i to imitate from a web site, they seem to use precise blending techniques and possibly manipulate their textures differently.
Attached Screenshot:
Current Implementation: Semi-transparent color applied, texture faintly visible.
Desired Effect: Texture remains more prominent,
What adjustments should I make to improve this, or is there a better method to achieve this type of overlay effect? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried:
Adjusting background-blend-mode values:
I've tried multiply, overlay, and screen. Multiply works best but still doesn't achieve the vivid texture I'm aiming for.
Experimenting with transparency:
Lowering the alpha value in rgba increases texture visibility but reduces the color's presence.
Using pseudo-elements:
Ensuring the texture and color overlay are properly stacked using a ::after pseudo-element.
Here’s an example of my code:


/**
 * Apply an overlay color to the image container.
 * @param {string} colorCode - The hex color code to apply (e.g., "#bdada2").
 */
function applyOverlayColor(colorCode) {
  const imageContainer = document.getElementById("pattern-image");

  if (colorCode) {
    // Convert hex color to RGBA with 50% transparency
    const transparentColor = hexToRgba(colorCode, 0.5);
    imageContainer.style.setProperty("--overlay-color", transparentColor); // Set dynamic overlay color
    imageContainer.setAttribute("data-color-overlay", "true"); // Enable overlay
  } else {
    // Reset overlay to transparent if no color is selected
    imageContainer.style.setProperty("--overlay-color", "transparent");
    imageContainer.removeAttribute("data-color-overlay"); // Disable overlay
  }
}

/**
 * Convert a hex color to RGBA format.
 * @param {string} hex - The hex color code (e.g., "#bdada2").
 * @param {number} alpha - The alpha value for transparency (0 to 1).
 * @returns {string} - The RGBA color string (e.g., "rgba(189, 173, 162, 0.5)").
 */
function hexToRgba(hex, alpha) {
  const r = parseInt(hex.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(hex.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(hex.slice(5, 7), 16);
  return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${alpha})`;
}

// Example: Apply overlay color on button click (you can replace this logic)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const sampleColor = "#bdada2"; // Replace with a dynamically selected color
  applyOverlayColor(sampleColor); // Apply the overlay to the image
});
/* Styling for the image container */
.template-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* Matches the width of the parent element */
  height: auto; /* Adjusts height based on the image aspect ratio */
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures overlay doesn't go outside the container */
}

/* Ensure the image fills the container */
.template-image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Pseudo-element for overlay */
.template-image-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent; /* Default is fully transparent */
  background-blend-mode: multiply; /* Ensures overlay blends with texture */
  pointer-events: none; /* Allows interactions with underlying image */
  z-index: 1; /* Places overlay above the image */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition on color change */
}

/* When an overlay color is applied */
.template-image-container[data-color-overlay="true"]::after {
  background-color: var(--overlay-color, transparent); /* Dynamic overlay color */
}
<div class="template-image-container" id="pattern-image">
  <!-- Placeholder image for demonstration -->
  <img
    src="https://i.imgur.com/lD0NBBd.png" 
    alt="Template with overlay" 
    class="template-image" 
  />
</div>




By leaving out the HTML and the texture image itself, you make it harder for people to answer your question. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

thanks i updated my post. i am a bit of a noob :)

OK. I don't think there's much wrong with your attempt, apart from the texture image itself. It is transparent, letting through the white background. When I make the background color of the body black it seems to work reasonably well: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mybymvN

KIKO this here is a big help, this really made a big change. now i just need to perfect it. Thanks a lot :) The issue is resolved i would say. How do i mark this as solved?

I don't really have any programming skill, very little html and css skills that's it. i am making a big project with chatGPT i have come a long way so far, and it's much fun. next is integrating AI. what a ride i am on :)

I also made a perfect copy now, mine is on the left side of the image. Just need a little more adjustment.
https://ibb.co/ZGQyfpQ. thanks again KIKO Software

I'm glad it helped. Sorry, you can only mark an answer as solving your question, not a comment. I won't write an answer to this question, because the cause of your problem is rather basic. It's probably best to delete this question since similar answers already exist. I would also strongly advice to reduce the usage of ChatGPT as much as possible, if you want to learn programming. You cannot make a "big project" with it. The danger here is that you don't actually understand what it's doing. This question is likely a symptom of that.

I'm not sure what conclusion you came to during you discussions with KIKO, but did you eventually think about putting the color behind the texture:https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b8axv39w/?
